# How to navigate to another file using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code like given below

```
<div id="content">
<h1>SITE INFORMATION!</h1>
<div id="taskList"></div>
<label for="taskName">Enter a site name:</label>
<input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
<label id="error" style="display:none"></label>
<label for="taskName">Enter a site no:</label>
<input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
<label id="error" style="display:none"></label>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b"></input>
<button type="next" onclick="go()">next</button>
<script> 
    function go(){
        // Some code  
    } 
 </script> 
 </div>
```

But the problem is on clicking the next button i need to display another file(probably .vm file) located in my system folder.
The file will be in my local system and when i am accessing by browser the above page that file needs to be displayed.

Can you please help me out in doing this

Comment: Use `window.location` `onclick="window.location='http://google.com'"`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for that, simple `window.location code` will do it, e.g.:

```
window.location.href = myUrl;

window.location.href = "/somewhere/else";
```

Answer (score 1):

Define "system folder"?

Technically, you can do this by using `onclick="window.location.href='/path/to/some/file'"` but that won't work if the file you're trying to get to is higher than your web root.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the information requested in this page to the next page the easiest way would be to use a traditional HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="./next.html">
  <label for="taskName">Enter a site name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
  <label id="error" style="display:none"></label>
  <label for="taskName">Enter a site no:</label>
  <input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
  <label id="error" style="display:none"></label>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b"></input>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Notice that your `<button type="next" />` is now `<input type="submit" />` hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery load:

```
$( 'target' ).load( "you_file_path", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```